# Jquery after ajax loaded in view

Tags: views, javascript, ajax

So I created a view listing all the users. I implement a search form with autosubmit function.

The autosubmit works with an ajax script.

Into my page view, I changed a few things in Jquery like this (main.js) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //code for others pages.....
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   $('h2').text('filters');
});
```

**But when I filter my list of users, the ajax script is loading and after that, Jquery changes do not appear due to ajax load.**

Do you know a trick to keep Jquery changes when ajax script is loading ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Add an ajaxComplete function

```
   $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
      $('h2').text('filters');
    });
```

Comment: I edit my post btw, It does not work

Comment: @CorentinBranquet I assumed you were just focusing on the snipped rather than the entire code. Since I thought you got the document ready function to work.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Find the solution below:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.events = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('#views-exposed-form-recherche-artiste-page', context).ajaxSuccess(function(){
         $('h2').text('filters');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Tried your solution but it still not working for me. Should i change something else apart from my view ID? i'm using Views Load More, and my code doesn't work after getting more news in my view